# Why declare org.apache.thrift.TException on every interface method?

Tags: java, thrift

Generating the [Thrift tutorial](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/thrift/?p=thrift.git;a=blob;f=tutorial/tutorial.thrift;h=c8710d418cabd29ba07f2714c01c00d19090d7cc;hb=HEAD) to Java, generates an interface `Calculator.Iface` where each method declares to throw a TException. **Why?**

Why not just keep it clean with business logic?

EDIT: I guess the motivation is to know if something happened in the Thrift invocation. So why not make it a runtime exception? Anyone has a link to a document/conversation brain-storming Thrift's exceptions?

Comment: Please, please, please don't ignite the checked exceptions flamewar.  And the answer to your last question is "google does".

Comment: @StephenC - I meant Thrift specific document/conversation.

Answer (score 1):

> I guess the motivation is to know if something happened in the Thrift
>   invocation. So why not make it a runtime exception?

One reason that could have driven the decision is that it is easy to mis-configure a middle-man message protocol (like thrift or protobuf) with the wrong file that defines a structure. Protobuf for example also throws an [InvalidProtocolBufferException](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/InvalidProtocolBufferException) that extends `IOException` when you try to parse `ByteString` [into a structure](https://code.google.com/p/protobufeditor/source/browse/trunk/%20protobufeditor/Source/ProtoBufEditor/src/com/example/tutorial/AddressBookProtos.java?r=4&spec=svn4) thereby forcing you to handle it.

I'm not a fan of checked exceptions in any form either and have debated it in various forums and discussion arenas at length. A while back, a framework I was working on needed to support multiple message protocol bindings (like thrift, json, protobuf etc). I decided to handle the checked exceptions and throw them as a `RuntimeParsingException` should I encounter inconsistencies between a client and server structure.

It is not pragmatic to expect a client to handle a specific message level protocol exception (by making it mandatory) when that underlying message protocol can change tomorrow.